# Increase Frequency of IMU Sensor

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu, imu

I am using an IMU sensor in gazebo. I want to change the frequency of the IMU but it does not change. I changed IMU `update_rate` also `max_step` size but there is no difference. Actually, the IMU frequency does not exceed 25 Hz. I want it to be 80 Hz.
What can I do?

Change IMU frequency in `igniton-gazebo`

```
<sensor name="imu" type="imu">
        <always_on>1</always_on>
        <update_rate>200</update_rate>
        <visualize>true</visualize>
        <topic>imu</topic>
        <enable_metrics>true</enable_metrics>
      </sensor>
```

```
<world name="rovercopter">
    <physics name="1ms" type="ode">
      <max_step_size>0.005</max_step_size>
      <real_time_factor>0.8</real_time_factor>
 <plugin
      filename="ignition-gazebo-imu-system"
      name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Imu">
    </plugin>
</world>
```

Comment: More information is needed. You'll need to share your XML file if you want any actual help.

Comment: I added the xml file for both model and world

Comment: I don't see a closing tag for `<physics name="1ms" …`.

Comment: I closed the tag.Xml file is too long ı want to show shortly

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your plugin has an update rate specified as well as the imu sensor

```
<plugin
  filename="ignition-gazebo-imu-system"
  name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Imu">
      <updateRate>80.0</updateRate>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can ı write the plugin tag?

Comment: @koray I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. The `updateRate` tag should be added to your existing plugin tag

Comment: Actually ı added the updateRate tag but ı cannot reach 80 Hz.

Comment: @koray what is the max rate you're getting? Possible you're hitting a system max?

Comment: Max ı gave 28 Hz.I can receive from ros nodes 80 Hz but not from gazebo